# Renditioned images seem to load slower than the full size version

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, image-rendition

I've created search result templates which display an image gallery (30-40 images per page) based on images uploaded to a picture library.

To avoid problems with end users uploading huge files, I'm initially displaying a 100x100 image rendition of each picture. This works great for reducing the file size of each image, ~300 kb to 5 kb.

The problem is that these renditioned images take longer overall to load than the full 300 kb versions. Checking the network tab in dev tools I can that some of the images have 3-4s initial response time. I wouldn't expect this as the files sizes are much larger. Does anyone know why this might be the case or of another way around this problem?

I'm on SharePoint Online, so cant configure anything to do with renditions in the background.

Thanks